# In Ionic 2, how to pass attribute data between two components?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I have a `CheckIn` page that has a `title` attribute.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'check-in.html'
})
export class CheckInPage {

  public title: string = 'Check In';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

I import this page in my `TabsPage`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckInPage } from '../check-in/check-in';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {

  public tab3Root: any;

  constructor() {
    this.tab3Root = CheckInPage;
  }
}
```

And now, I want to use it in my TabsPage view:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="{{tab3Root.title}}" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This gives me `undefined` when I `console.log` it. Please assist.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What are you trying to `console.log`? `this.tab3Root`?

Comment: @Huiting I'm just trying to access the `CheckInPage.title` attribute from where I imported `CheckInPage`: the `TabsPage`.

Comment: @KaMok, tabs doesn't work like that. The `tabTitle` attribute could only be a string, so you need to set the title statically. Do you want to change it later or why are you trying to use a `title` property instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to pass data between pages in Ionic, which are covered in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5iGAAypGBA

For brevity, I'll only cover one of those ways here: if it's something you want to persist between multiple pages you might do that via an Ionic 2 Provider.

You can generate a provider in the CLI:

```
ionic g provider DemoProvider
```

It will generate a provider which you can add variables to, like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the DemoProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DemoProvider {

  mySharedVariable: String = "Hello";

  constructor() {
  } 

}
```

In the component where you want to use the provider, make sure you import it, and inject it into the constructor:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DemoProvider } from '../../providers/demoProvider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  constructor(public demoProvider:DemoProvider) {

  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
        console.log(demoProvider.mySharedVariable);
  }

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've gotten a lot better in Ionic since I first opened this post and I already found my answer a long time ago. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try to assign the page to each tab outside of constructor. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/

html

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"><ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

js/ts

```
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
})

export class Tabs {
  // here we'll set the property of chatRoot to
  // the imported class of ChatPage
  chatRoot = ChatPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

You can give this a try.

Comment: I've done this already. Doesn't work. Have you got this to work successfully?

Comment: I am using an older version of Ionic (`2.0.0-beta.4`) so the syntax is slightly different from the newer version. My code looks similar to the one you posted.

Comment: When you say it doesnt work, able to elaborate? Is the page showing only the tabs but not the correct tab view? Or is there no tabs shown at all